# How to host WCF service to call from out of LAN network

Tags: wcf

I created a WCF service and hosted it on my IIS. It's working fine on my LAN, but I can't call the service from outside of my LAN network. Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

First try to ping the IP of IIS. If reply comes then try to ping the Service, as such nothing special is needed to access service out of network, only static ip must be there on the machine where you have hosted it

Comment: How can I get my static ip from my ISP?

Comment: _"try to ping the Service"_ - how? And for _"as such nothing special is needed to access service out of network"_: there probably is, it's not good if a machine is directly accessible from outside networks, in this case the internet.

Comment: internet means going for a monthly pay web server?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't call the service from out of my LAN network

I assume the service runs on port 80 in IIS and you're behind [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

You can solve this by mapping port 80 from your external IP in your router's NAT or virtual server page (see portforward.com) to the private range IP of the machine hosting IIS.

Also note the security implications of hosting a publicly accessible website on a machine, you don't want it pwned.

Comment: Yes I opened the port 80 in my router, but still its not working

Comment: @PrasadMari _"Not working"_ is not an error. Have you tried accessing the machine through the external IP on port 80? Is it forwarded to the correct internal IP address? Are you sure you can access port 80 from the internal network already? Is there another firewall between IIS and the internet? How did you try to access it, from the same network but through the external IP? Does the router support NAT loopback? Otherwise that probably won't work. Can you access it from another, say mobile, network? Please show what you have tried.

Comment: I opened the port 80 in my router configuration and connected my client machine to another LAN network, same time I disabled my both internet security and machine firewall, but no answer

Comment: "another LAN network"? Are you using `DualHttpBinding` by any chance?

Comment: first I tried wshttpbinding no answer, then I tried DualHttpBinding again no solution